# Why is perspective not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a very basic 3D square.

```
 div {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background: #333;
 transform: rotateX(50deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(50deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateX(50deg);
 -ms-transform: rotateX(50deg);
 Perspective: 300px;
 -webkit-Perspective: 300px;
 -moz-Perspective: 300px;
 -ms-Perspective: 300px;
 }
```

Testing on chrome, RotateX works (as in the box height shrinks) but there's no perspective. Perspective property isn't working. I don't get it, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define [`perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective), that `perspective` view is set for child element and not for the element itself so try nesting your element inside another.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yVPF7/1/)

[Here's](http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/) a nice article to get you going ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the `perspective` property to an *ancestor* of the element to which you apply the `transform` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/rPwRD/